# Search and replace not working for ACF Images

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, wpdb

I just connected a staging site from IP Address to a live domain. I ran search and replace on everything from IP Address to domain name.

I mistakenly added the trailing slash after the domain name like (search for IP 12345 and replace with domain.com/)

I have managed to fix all incorrect links, except the ones I am using for ACF. For ACF the images are still domain.com/domain.com/wp-content/uploads/imagefile.jpg

How can I remove the duplication of the domain name from the image file to make the image appear again?

I have tried Better Search and Replace Plugin, Migrate Wordpress DB Plugin, even Interconnect Search and Replace DB plugin but no luck at all.

Comment: Doesn't searching for `domain.com/domain.com/` and replacing it with `domain.com/` work?

Comment: have you tried using wp-cli?

Comment: Please see my answer to BlueDogRanch Answer

Answer (score 1):

Use https://www.phpmyadmin.net/ or https://www.adminer.org/ (available on many web hosts or install yourself) and use the overall search function to search for an instance of the string `domain.com/domain.com` so you can the find the exact problem string, and also find which tables the ACF data is stored in. The strings might be in wp_posts, or wp_postmeta or even wp_options.

Once you find an instance of the bad string, you will see the exact format of the string - trailing slash, no trailing slash, etc - and you can try using Interconnect again, which is the safest method to correct the strings.

You can also manually edit each string in each database record with PHPMyAdmin or Adminer.

If Intercconnect doesn't work for some reason, you can use a query such as

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://domain.com/domain.com/', 'http://domain.com/');
```

in the SQL Query function in PHPMyAdmin or Adminer to bulk replace the strings. That query will find/replace post content in the `wp_posts` table. But simulate the query first in PHPMyAdmin or Adminer, and back up your database beforehand.

https://wp-cli.org/ is also a good choice, but you need to know that you are searching for the correct string before using WP CLI.

Comment: Thanks for the above. So I checked in PHP My Admin and this is how ACF has stored the images as value: meta_key = product_features // meta_value = a:6:{i:0;s:22:"Comfortable round grip";i:1;s:16:"Fully adjustable";i:2;s:21:"Genuine leather cuffs";i:3;s:41:"Improved control and behaviour correction";i:4;s:17:"Non-slip function";i:5;s:10:"Reflective";}

There is no direct link of the respective image

Comment: If you can't find `domain.com/domain.com` in the database, that means it's hardcoded in php in the theme file that uses the ACF data, or it's in the actual output of ACF.